# one-to-many or one-to-one, what to use here?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relationship

actually I am a bit confused now, after reading when to use 1:1, 1:n and n:m

First a basic question: if I have two tables:

```
users      roles
-----      -----
user_id    role_id
role_id    ....
....
```

and have a FK `fk_users_roles1`, is this n:1 (many users can have one role)?

---

and a second question to that:

```
users    companies    companymembers
-----    ---------    --------------
user_id  company_id   company_id
                      user_id
```

with two FKs in `companymembers`: `fk_companymembers_companies1` and `fk_companymembers_users1`, what is the correct relation here? 1:1 or 1:n?

Comment: For the first, you are right, it is 1:n (a user has only **1** role, a role can be assigned to **many** users). For the second case, it is a n:m relationship (a user can be member of **many** companies, a company can have **many** users as members).

Comment: thanks! so if I want a user to be a member of only one company I should do it like with the roles?